# jsonb save array column jsonb postgres rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I work with vue js and rails. I send to rails my list of campos

```
data() {
      return {    
          campos: [{nombre: "(label)", valor: "", editable: false,soltoTecla: false}]

        };
    },
```

In my rails method when I save the array of campos

```
data_campos = params[:dataCampos].to_json(:only =>[:nombre, :valor]) 
@proyecto.update(campos: data_campos)
```

Why the array campos save with

```
[{\"nombre\":\"(label)\",\"valor\":\"telefono\"},{\"nombre\":\"(label)\",\"valor\":\"\"},{\"nombre\":\"(label)\",\
```

In database column?

The column is type jsonb and my Postgres version is 9.5

The expected format is:

```
{"dataCampos": [{"nombre"=>"(label)", "valor"=>"", "editable"=>false, "soltoTecla"=>false}, {"nombre"=>"eee", "valor"=>"", "editable"=>false, "soltoTecla"=>true}]}
```

Comment: What is expected format?

Comment: the expected format is: {"dataCampos": [{"nombre"=>"(label)", "valor"=>"", "editable"=>false, "soltoTecla"=>false}, {"nombre"=>"eee", "valor"=>"", "editable"=>false, "soltoTecla"=>true}]}

Comment: `{a: 1}.to_json` => `"{\"a\":1}"` The format seems to be correct